# Found Option[CSVWriter] but required CSVWriter? `var` caused the issue?

Tags: scala

The following code

```
var writers = new HashMap[String, CSVWriter]()

  var writer = writers.get(pool)
  if (writer == null) {
    //writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(s"..."))
    writers.put(pool, writer) // Errr
  }
```

Got the error of

```
[error]  found   : Option[au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter]
[error]  required: au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter
[error]         writers.put(pool, writer)
[error]                           ^
[error] one error found
```

Does `var` automatically add an `Option` wrapper? What I should do to put `CSVWriter` in the hashmap?

Comment: No, the `get` method on Scala's `Map` returns an `Option[T]`, because the value could be missing... You can use `writers(pool)` if you want an exception.. xD

Comment: What's the isomorphic way to do it in Scala?

Comment: Idiomatic Scala would be `val maybeWriter = writers.get(pool)` `maybeWriter.map{writer => ....}`. Or, if you also want to handle the case when the writer is missing `maybeWriter match { case Some(writer) => {...} case None => { ...}}`

Comment: Thanks. I used the pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

When a value is retrieved from a HashMap in scala using .get(key), the default returned value is of Option instance.

```
scala> val writers = collection.mutable.HashMap("abc" -> "def")
writers: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,String] = Map(abc -> def)

scala> writers.get("abc")
res10: Option[String] = Some(def)
```

Option will return Some instance if the key exists in the HashMap and returns None if the key is not present.

```
scala> writers.get("a")
res13: Option[String] = None
```

This helps to avoid the nullpointer exceptions.

We need to get the real value using another get

```
scala> writers.get("abc").get
res11: String = def
```

But to be on the safe-side we can use getOrElse

```
scala> writers.getOrElse("abc", "no value")
res1: String = def

scala> writers.getOrElse("a", "no value")
res2: String = no value
```

I hope the explanation is clear